# What's The Difference Between These? & What should I use?

Tags: c++, system, volume

I want to make a system that will only allow you to use my program on one computer, kind of like a licence system.
ex: program checks volume information of system, if matches with the volume that allows it to run, it runs.

My 2 questions are,
1. What's the difference between these 2 ways of getting system volume?

```
int main()
{
    cout << GetVolumeInformation << endl;
    system("pause");
}

string GetMachineID()
{
    DWORD dwSerial;
    ostringstream oss;

    if (!GetVolumeInformation(TEXT("C:\\"), NULL, 0, &dwSerial, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0))
    {
        oss << "Err_Not_Retrieved_" << GetLastError();
    }
    else
        oss << dwSerial;

    return oss.str();
}

string machid = GetMachineID();
const char *cstr = machid.c_str();

int main()
{
    cout << cstr << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

They each return a different value, (first: xxxxxxxx numbers and letters, second: xxxxxxxxxx only numbers ) so what's the difference?
And my second question is, which one of these should I use for my purpose?

Comment: Your first attempt prints out a function address...

Comment: your title is non-descriptive. change it to something sensible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first program is returning a pointer to the function GetVolumeInformation, which is a huge difference from the second program, which gets the volume information and returns the serial when valid.

You definitely don't want to use the first one for two reasons. First, it's not system-dependent (or even program-dependent in that it can differ wildly from launch to launch). Secondly, (and probably most importantly) it doesn't accomplish anything remotely close to what you want it to.